# Do I have to include all classes in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am planning to retrieve the content from a text file and store them on objects with reference to class. So I have a list of text files containing data about marks of 20 student from two different class in 3 subjects.
My task is to calculate total marks of each student and store them in two different text files with rank of each student in each class.

For the class diagram I'm showing **student** and **class** as a two main classes for my application. [image] Do I have to mention all classes in class diagram that I have used in my program.

E.g. currently apart from **student** and **class** class , I'm using **input** class and **output** class to retrieve and store data in text file.
Do I have to mention them in class diagram as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are free to chose what classes to show in your class diagram.  You can even use different diagrams showing different details of the same model if you want.

In fact, your current choice corresponds to what we usually call a domain model:  you show only classes relevant to the domain (i.e. business). This is the kind of diagram that can be used to discuss with the users, because you mention only classes they know in real life.

A more comprehensive design diagram could add other important classes of your solution, but which are not directly relevant for the users (e.g. input and output to represent the file objects).  And an implementation diagram would show all the classes to be implemented with all the details (if this is useful of course).

Minor remarks about your diagram:

- `Student` in *italic* would mean that it is an abstract class with some operations that are yet to be provided by a specialization. If this was not your intent, get rid of the fancy font.
- prefer `0..*`  to `0-m`